# How to make a file writeable for its owner?

Tags: linux

Linux newbie here, working on Debian Jessie.

Why does `chmod u+w` not make a file writeable for its owner?

I have run:

```
sudo chmod u+w /var/log/myapp/gunicorn-error.log
```

But now if I list the permissions on the file, it still doesn’t seem to be writeable:

```
ls -al /var/log/myapp/
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  2 opuser webapps  4096 Sep  1 11:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root   root     4096 Sep  1 11:24 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 opuser webapps     0 Aug 23 07:11 gunicorn-access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 opuser webapps 38639 Sep  1 11:15 gunicorn-error.log
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please elaborate what is the problem and why do you think it isn't writable by the owner? Do you want group writable?

Comment: per your `ls -al` the files are both writable by their owner `opuser`, so neither you nor chmod are doing anything wrong. please explain why you think that somthing is not correct.

Comment: Ah - I thought permissions went right to left, not left to right! Thanks.

Comment: I won't call this a dupe though, since it's not the same question (the answer to this question is a subset of the answer to the suggested question, but it's not the same *question*, from the point of anyone Googling with the same problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your presented command and related output seem fine; not too sure what you believe is going wrong. You simply issued this [`chmod`](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) command via symbolic mode:

```
sudo chmod u+w /var/log/myapp/gunicorn-error.log
```

And then this is the result:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 opuser webapps 38639 Sep  1 11:15 gunicorn-error.log
```

From left to right

- The first `rw-` is for the user/owner of the file.
- The next `r--` indicates group permissions.
- The final `r--` is permissions for others.

So knowing that, your `chmod u+w` succeeded because the user/owner has `rw-` permissions.

That said, if somehow your concern is about the group and other permissions, changing the permissions for the user/owner via symbolic mode *does not negate existing permissions* for the group and other permissions.

If you somehow want to set read and write for a user/owner *but negate permissions for the group and others*, you need to run a `chmod` with an absolute (octal) mode setting like this:

```
sudo chmod 600 /var/log/myapp/gunicorn-error.log
```

Which would result in permissions like this:

```
-rw-------  1 opuser webapps 38639 Sep  1 11:15 gunicorn-error.log
```

While harder to remember for most casual users, the main benefit of the absolute (octal) mode method is you can set multiple aspects of permissions in one command.

In contrast, symbolic mode makes setting permissions easier to read and remember, but you might need to issue a few symbolic mode commands in a row to achieve the same final result the absolute (octal) mode can achieve in one command.